# Get function inside default export function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have function inside `user.js` with default export like this

```
export default {  
  var getListFriends = async (accessToken) =>{
  }
  ....other function
  return {
    getListFriends,
    ...other function...
  }
}
```

then I import it to index.js

```
import userService from './user';
```

Then I will add only index.js to plugin.

I can call `this.$userService` (it shows as anonymous function) but `this.$userService.getListFriends` return undefined.

How can I call function `getListFriends` from import.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

where is user.js?
if its inside plugins directory, you have to use inject to add it to your nuxt.

then you can access it via nuxt object inside your code.
see this example from nuxt docs:

```
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  // Inject $hello(msg) in Vue, context and store.
  inject('hello', msg => console.log(`Hello ${msg}!`))
}
```

you can see the full document [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context)

Comment: I have multiples files like user.js, I want to import all of these files to only index.js file. and in index.js, I will inject each service for each files. 
Import multiples file to plugin is not good idea.

Comment: the question is where do you want to use these functions?

Comment: if you want to use them inside your compoents or pages, you need to create multiple plugins for each function, dont inject all of them in one. if you want to use them every where, add it to your utlis directory then import them anywhere you wnt to use them. you cant import all off your functions in the index.js file, nuxt does not support it and its  bad practice. you need to use import where ever you want to use them with utils or use plugins

Comment: Can you check my updated question

Comment: i wrote another answer for your question hope the other one works for you

Answer (score 0):

ok now for this to work the way you want you need to change your user.js file,

```
export default {
  friends: () => {
    console.log('hi bro');
  },
  notFriends: () => {
    console.log('go away man im not your bro');
  }
};
```

something like this.
you dont need inject or app in your user.js.
and your code problem is that you are defining a function and trying to access it's inner values from the outside like:

```
function boo() {
  var b = 0;
}
```

you can not access the value of b with boo.b. its a local variable to the boo function

instead create a object and have multiple functions inside your object

Comment: Mamdasan, I need to inject app to user.js for purpose call any assigned context. It is reason why I use it as function. Let see in my question, I already return the function

Comment: well if you can show me the complete code of user.js i might be able to help

Comment: It is all code of user file.

Comment: then i dont understand where you used app or inject in that piece of code, 
you might try using
try this:  inject('userService', userService());
this might work

Comment: the problems is that your user.js file is a function. and you want to access a prop inside of your function. the design have problem. you cant access values of functions. the best way is return an object form your user.js file